# how to play audio file from url in android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audio-player

I need to play audio file from remote server in my app. I could play when I tested with localhost server (using WAMP). When the same file supplied from the server it is not working..
The file has no extension and the content is MP3

```
String fileUrl = "http://192.168.1.131/myproject/songs/xyz";
String url = "http://myserver/songs/xyz"; //(myserver -> A remote server)
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(fileUrl));
mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

Also I need to have a better control over player.

Please help...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public void onRadioClick(View v) {

    if (!isPLAYING) {
        isPLAYING = true;
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(getString(R.string.audio_stream));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    } else {
        isPLAYING = false;
        stopPlaying();
    }
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The answer provided above provides synchronous fetching and playing, meaning currently executing thread will be blocked until prepare() is completed.

prepareAsync() can be used instead to "prepare" the stream asynchronously. You also will need to handle onPrepared() event to start playing.

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL here);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Add OnPrepared event handler:

```
mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Still, apparently there is no way to configure streaming buffer size. Frustrating...

Comment: To configure streaming buffer size into custom blocks Google recommends using it's [ExoPlayer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/). It's what the YouTube app uses right now and works for mp3 streaming.

Comment: If you want to play audio only, then you should go with MediaPlayer because ExoPlayer consumes more battery than MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 5):

```
> import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.google.ads.Ad;
import com.google.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import com.google.ads.InterstitialAd;

/**
 * @author Rashid Ali
 * @Date Sep 18, 2014
 * @Email <rashid.android.developer@gmail.com>
 * 
 */

public class AudioPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener,
        AdListener {

    private ProgressDialog progressBar;

    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE = "ca-app-pub-5453344383403527/5064575693";
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    private ImageButton buttonPlayPause;
    private SeekBar seekBarProgress;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds; // this value contains the song
                                                // duration in milliseconds.
                                                // Look at getDuration() method
                                                // in MediaPlayer class

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    String audioName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_player);

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE);
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(this);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        initilizeUI();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        audioName = intent.getStringExtra("audioName");

    }

    /** This method is used to Initialize UI Components. */
    private void initilizeUI() {
        buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause);
        buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        seekBarProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBarTestPlay);
        seekBarProgress.setMax(99);
        seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Method which updates the SeekBar primary progress by current song playing
     * position
     */
    private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
        seekBarProgress.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer
                .getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds) * 100)); // This
                                                                                // math
                                                                                // construction
                                                                                // give
                                                                                // a
                                                                                // percentage
                                                                                // of
                                                                                // "was playing"/"song length"
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        /**
         * Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song
         * loading from URL position
         */
        seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        /**
         * MediaPlayer onCompletion event handler. Method which calls then song
         * playing is complete
         */
        // buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.SeekBarTestPlay) {
            /**
             * Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to
             * seekBar primary progress position
             */
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
                int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100)
                        * sb.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause) {
            /**
             * ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause
             * mediaplayer playing
             */
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioName); // setup
                                                        // song
                                                        // from
                                                        // http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3
                                                        // URL
                                                        // to
                                                        // mediaplayer
                                                        // data
                                                        // source
                mediaPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup
                                        // the datasource in setDataSource
                                        // method. After calling prepare() the
                                        // instance of MediaPlayer starts load
                                        // data from URL to internal buffer.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // song
                                                                        // length
                                                                        // in
                                                                        // milliseconds
                                                                        // from
                                                                        // URL

            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button);

            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
            }
            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (ad == interstitialAd) {
            interstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

}
```

> 

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_header" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/googleads"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5453344383403527/9634376094"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/googleads"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5453344383403527/2111109291"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/functional_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ButtonTestPlayPause"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/play_button" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/SeekBarTestPlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonTestPlayPause" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing Java programs to play media files, then the first port of call is the MediaPlayer class. Typical code to play a file using the streaming mechanism of MediaPlayer is

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.9/music/test.ogg");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(this, uri);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Wake Lock Permission - If your player application needs to keep the screen from dimming or the processor from sleeping, or uses the MediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying() or MediaPlayer.setWakeMode() methods, you must request this permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following Kotlin extension for url streaming by using `MediaPlayer`

```
fun ImageButton.playFromUrl(
    url: String,
    onStart: MediaPlayer.() -> Unit
) {
    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build()

    MediaPlayer().apply {
        setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
        setDataSource(url)

        setOnPreparedListener {
            isEnabled = false
            start()
            setImageDrawable(context.getDrawableResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_stop_24))
        }

        setOnCompletionListener {
            setImageDrawable(context.getDrawableResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_volume_up_24))
            release()
            isEnabled = true
        }
    }.onStart()
}
```

the usage of above function like below

```
btnVoice.setOnSingleClickListener {
    if(it.isInternetAvailable()){
        (it as ImageButton).playFromUrl(phonetic.audio){
            prepareAsync()
        }
    }
}
```