# Custom push notification sounds in android, which served server-side

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM to send push notifications to my android apps.
I put some notification sounds in my `res` folder to use different sounds by setting a key-value pair in my JSON. That works fine with no problem.

Now my question is that:

Is it possible to serve the sounds server-side, so there is no need to put them in `res` folder and I'm not restricted to the sounds in `res` folder?

Comment: GCM has max message size of 4KB. Hence sending large amounts of data through these systems is not possible. You should use GCM to send a small message to the device indicating that the device should request the large data `payload` directly from the application server. For more details, please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#payload). So i think you save the sounds on your server, and use the GCM to tell app where can load the data.

Comment: @bjiang thanks. I know that I have to save them on my server, I want to know is it possible to play the notification sound with a URL? Can you send me an android code?

Comment: You can use the `MediaPlayer` to play the sound for the notification. Check the code here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974392/how-to-play-audio-file-from-url-in-android

Comment: @bjiang Thanks, but if I use `mediaPlayer`, the sound volume isn't managed by notification volume and is managed by media volume. So if a device is set to vibrate or mute(muting a device will not set media volum to mute too) ,  it will play the notification sound. And it has a bad experience for users.